# generate pdf of each record in database table and send as attachment to email

Tags: java, mysql, wamp, jakarta-mail

I have 4 records in database table. The table has columns id, name, score1, score2, score3, total, email. each record has a different email. the purpose of the code is to loop through each record, generate a pdf for each record by the records 'id' and send pdf as email to the email value of the record. i used the while loop but hard as i try, my code rather generates pdf of all the records and sends to each recipient email. 'i only want it to generate pdf of only each record and send to the recipients email at a time'. cant really tell where i am going wrong.

```
try{
String sql="select * from score_table where id=score_table.id";
pst=con.prepareStatement(sql);
rs=pst.executeQuery();
// Loop through each record
while (rs.next()) {
  // Retrieve data for current record
  String name = rs.getString("name");
  String score1 = rs.getString("score1");
  String score2 = rs.getString("score2");
  String score3 = rs.getString("score3");
  String score4 = rs.getString("score4"); 
  int total = rs.getInt("total");
  String recipientEmail = rs.getString("email");

  // Create parameters for the report
  Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();
  parameters.put("name", name);
  parameters.put("score1", score1);
  parameters.put("score2", score2);
  parameters.put("score3", score3);
  parameters.put("score4", score4);
  parameters.put("total", total);

  // Load report template
  JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport("studentSco.jrxml");

  // Populate report with data
  JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, con);

  // Export report to PDF file
  byte[] pdfBytes = JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf(jasperPrint);

  // Create new email message
  Properties props = new Properties();
  props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
  props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
  props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
  props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
  props.setProperty("mail.smtp.ssl.protocols", "TLSv1.2");

  Session session = Session.getInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
    @Override
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication("rodysoftonline@gmail.com", "wdmssbarmwfgxxxw");
    }
});

  Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
  message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("rodysoftonline@gmail.com"));
  message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipientEmail));
  message.setSubject("Report for " + name);

MimeBodyPart attachment = new MimeBodyPart();
ByteArrayDataSource source = new ByteArrayDataSource(pdfBytes, "application/pdf");
attachment.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
attachment.setFileName("report_" + name + ".pdf");

  Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
  multipart.addBodyPart(attachment);

  message.setContent(multipart);

  // Send email
  Transport.send(message);
  System.out.println("email sent successfully");
}
    }catch(SQLException | MessagingException | JRException e){
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
}
// Close database connection and resources
finally{
try{
rs.close();
pst.close();
  }
catch(SQLException e){
      }
        }
```

This is what i have so far. though its in a while loop, it only generates pdf for all records once and sends to each email in record. i want it to generate pdf for only each record and send to record's email, generate pdf of next record, send to email and so on... till its done with all records in the table

Comment: Your design would be better if you refactored the schema to 3rd normal form: one-to-many between receiver and score tables.    Sounds like you have PDF generation with the loop over records inside.  You need to reverse those two: loop over records and create a PDF inside that loop.  Your code is doing too much: query the database, create PDFs, send emails with attachments.  Refactor and test each method individually.

Comment: Your email routine is sub-optimal too. You should establish the `Session` before the loop and send *in it*

Comment: was thinking thats what i did @duffymo . it seems am not being able to grasp it entirely. kindly give me a sample code let me follow. thanks

Comment: i tried establishing the ```session``` before the loop but still same issue @g00se .

Comment: You need to post the jrxml file too

Comment: still same issue @g00se. am thinking the issue has to do with ```Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();``` . i believe its loading all records instead of a single record from the database. just trying hard to find the issue. if you have any sample code kingly let it assist me. thanks @g00se

Comment: Where is the jrxml?

Comment: its in my main project folder @g00se. so i refer to it in the code like this : ```jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport("studentScore.jrxml");``` i am able to send the pdf to all emails successfully. but the issue is it loads all records of the database into the jrxml file before converting to pdf. i printed out values in the ```Map<String, Object> parameters = new HarshMap<>()``` and it loaded each single record at a time. i just dont know how all records loaded into jrxml file

Comment: I wanted you to post the jrxml. I'm guessing you're doing the full query in that and that it's filling the report

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I might refactor your code.  I end up with four interfaces and four classes.  You'd need to add implementations for two of the interfaces.

Start with an encapsulation for your data - `User`:

```
package report;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class User {

    private final String name;

    private final String email;
    private final List<Double> scores;

    public User(String name, String email, List<Double> scores) {
        if ((name == null) || (name.trim().length() == 0)) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Name cannot be blank or null");
        if ((email == null) || (email.trim().length() == 0)) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Email cannot be blank or null");
        this.name = name.trim();
        this.email = email.trim();
        this.scores = (scores != null) ? new ArrayList<>(scores) : new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public List<Double> getScores() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(scores);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        User user = (User) o;

        if (!getName().equals(user.getName())) return false;
        if (!getEmail().equals(user.getEmail())) return false;
        return getScores().equals(user.getScores());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = getName().hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + getEmail().hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + getScores().hashCode();
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", email='" + email + '\'' +
                ", scores=" + scores +
                '}';
    }
}
```

I created the User class using IntelliJ 2023.1, running under JDK 17.  It might be a good case for using a record class.

Create an interface `UserRepository` and an implementation that does nothing but interact with your relational database:

```
package report;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public interface UserRepository {

    User findByName(String name);

    default void close(ResultSet rs) {
        try {
            if (rs != null) {
                rs.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // log at best
        }
    }
    default void close(Statement st) {
        try {
            if (st != null) {
                st.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // log at best.
        }
    }

    default void close(Connection connection) {
        try {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // log at best.
        }
    }
}
```

Here's an implementation:

```
package report;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class UserRepositoryImpl implements UserRepository {

    public static final String FIND_BY_NAME = "SELECT NAME, EMAIL, SCORE1, SCORE2, SCORE3, SCORE4 FROM SCORE_TABLE WHERE NAME = ?";

    private final Connection connection;

    public UserRepositoryImpl(Connection connection) {
        this.connection = connection;
    }

    @Override
    public User findByName(String name) {
        User user;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        try {
            ps = this.connection.prepareStatement(FIND_BY_NAME);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            user = new UserMapper().mapRow(rs);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } finally {
            close(rs);
            close(ps);
        }
        return user;
    }
}
```

The repository implementation uses a `RowMapper` interface and a `UserMapper` implementation:

```
package report;

import java.sql.ResultSet;

public interface RowMapper<T> {
    T mapRow(ResultSet rs);
}
```

Here is the implementation from a `UserMapper`:

```
package report;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class UserMapper implements RowMapper<User> {

    @Override
    public User mapRow(ResultSet rs) {
        User user = null;
        try {
            while (rs.next()) {
                String name = rs.getString("NAME");
                String email = rs.getString("EMAIL");
                List<Double> scores = new ArrayList<>();
                scores.add(rs.getDouble("SCORE1"));
                scores.add(rs.getDouble("SCORE2"));
                scores.add(rs.getDouble("SCORE3"));
                scores.add(rs.getDouble("SCORE4"));
                user = new User(name, email, scores);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            user = null;
        }
        return user;
    }
}
```

There are interfaces for your Jasper report generator and email client:

```
package report;

public interface JasperReportGenerator<T> {

    byte [] generate(String jrxml, T data);
}

package report;

public interface EmailClient {

    void send(String from, String to, String subject, String body, byte [] attachment);
}
```

This is more classes than your single method.  This approach has a few advantages:

- Each class does one thing well (single responsibility principle)
- It's easy to test each class individually using Junit.

See if this approach helps you.